# How to set environment with Derby Embedded + JPA 2.0 + Hibernate in a JavaEE application?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I have a JavaEE application where I need to use an embedded database (in memory). I do not want to have to configure anything in JBoss for this database. Thus, i do not want to use the JBoss data-sources.

I tried setting up in many different ways, but so far none worked. This is my current setup:

- JBoss: 7.1.1.Final
- Derby: 10.10.1.1
- Hibernate: 4.1.0.Final

Dependencies in Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
    <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
    <version>10.10.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>      
</dependency>    
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>              
</dependency>
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="TributarioEmbarcado" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

        <class>com.sysmo.client.tributario.baseEmbarcada.model.LoginEmbarcado</class>
        <class>com.sysmo.client.tributario.baseEmbarcada.model.ConfiguracaoEmbarcado</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url"   value="jdbc:derby:memory:sysmo_tributario_embarcado;create=true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="passwd" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

I tried to use the javax.persistence.* properties but seems not to work with the hibernate specific provider (org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence).

With that configuration, this error occurs when doing deploy on JBoss:

> ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (EJB default - 4) No suitable >driver found for jdbc:derby:memory:sysmo_tributario_embarcado;create=true

The class org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver is inside the Derby package which I have configured in maven. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

`

```
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"   value="jdbc:derby:dbname;create=true" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"       value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
```

`

It worked for me.